# In url %20 convert into a space how can fix this

Tags: php, url

I have a file name like this wk%2002_13 when it goes in url it converts into wk 02_13 and then file not found error ,how can i fix this error without changing the file name?

Comment: You need to escape the percent in the URL

Comment: Which part of the URL does this filename? Path or Query String?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function:

```
<?php
echo urlencode('wk%2002_13'); # yields 'wk%252002_13'
?>
```